# MySQL querying a junction table returns duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, join, junction-table

I have the following table structure:
[image]

So a product may have multiple `product_type`'s.

When I do my Join in MySQL I get repeated `product` records for each `product_type`. So for example if I have product called `Actifoam` and it has 2 records in the `products_types` table then the result of the query will include `Actifoam` twice (each one with a different `product_type`.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product.*, product_type.name as product_type_name
FROM products_types
JOIN product_type ON product_type.id = products_types.product_type_id
JOIN product ON product.id = products_types.product_id
```

Here is what the result of the query shows:

```
[
    0 => [
        'id' => 'recccAQHxsb4OEsX6'
        'name' => 'Actifoam'
        'product_type_name' => 'Silver Dressing'
    ]
    1 => [
        'id' => 'recccAQHxsb4OEsX6'
        'name' => 'Actifoam'
        'product_type_name' => 'Foam'
    ]
]
```

I don't want the `product` records to appear multiple times like this, I would like everything to appear on a single row if there are multiple `product_types`.

Anyone have an idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` will return unique rows only if 2 rows have exact same corresponding values for all columns in `SELECT` statement. In your case you need `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT`.

`GROUP_CONCAT` will return `product_type_name` separated by comma.

```
SELECT product.*, GROUP_CONCAT(product_type.name) as product_type_name
FROM products_types
JOIN product_type ON product_type.id = products_types.product_type_id
JOIN product ON product.id = products_types.product_id
GROUP BY product.id
```